# Manipulating Data in angular component/html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on a angular application. I have a html page with component. Once the application is compiled and runned, the html looks something like this.

```
IncomingTime  Name    Id  OutgoingTIme
```

In my html code is ass follows

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let service of newArray; let i = index">
                                <td class="time">{{service.IncomingTime}}</td>
                                <td class="dest">{{service.Name}}</td>
                                <td class="exp">{{service.ID}}</td>
                             <td class="exp">{{service.OutgointTIme}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
```

In component I am filling my newArray and It has data something like this

```
 newArray = [
    {
        "Name": "Andy",
        "Id": "1",
        "IncomingTime": "2020-06-19T11:02+00:00",
        "Outgoingtime": "2020-06-19T11:07+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Billy",
        "Id": "2",
        "IncomingTime": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00",
        "Outgoingtime": "2020-06-19T11:17+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ciena",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Doda",
        "Id": "4",
        "IncomingTime": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00",
        "Outgoingtime": "2020-06-19T11:07+00:00"
    }
    ];
```

When I run the application, It workd fine, It displays data. But I want to display "See NoticeBoard" when data except "Name" is not available. For example, In case of "Ciena", we have only Name, so when Ciena is displayed on screen I want to display "See NoticeBoard" in place of "Id" and "OutgotingTime". Something as follows

```
IncomingTime Name   Id OutgoingTime
             Ciena  See NoticeBoard
```

For rest others data should be visible. It  is just a example array, I can have many items in array at runtime so need a  generic solution for this, so that everytime only name is present "See NoticeBoard" is displayed every time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular ngIf directive [Link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description)

Example:

```js
<tr *ngFor="let service of newArray; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="service.OutgointTIme && service.IncomingTime"> <!-- Modify condition according your needs -->
    <td class="time">{{ service.IncomingTime }}</td>
    <td class="dest">{{ service.Name }}</td>
    <td class="exp">{{ service.ID }}</td>
    <td class="exp">{{ service.OutgointTIme }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!service.OutgointTIme || !service.IncomingTime"> <!-- Modify condition according your needs -->
    <td></td>
    <td class="dest">{{ service.Name }}</td>
    <td class="dest" colspan="2"><button>See Notice Board</button></td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use an else clause in the ngIf rather than test the negative condition again